# How to remove Ubercart properties from content types (SKU, list price)

Tags: ubercart, entities

In the concerned product type, at manage display, I unchecked SKU, list price etc but they still appear. Cleared browser and drupal cache. Any other setting I should be looking?

Comment: That could be a matter of theme. BTW, you mean the product page, or the products grid/list?

Comment: I've got 2 views, one with a list of products (which has the sku and list price) and a detailed view of a single product, where there is no sku and list price. So it's working, but not completely. I still need the 'hidden' to apply to de product overview page

Comment: The product overview page may be generated with a specific template, which can ignore your display settings. I would use the [Theme Developer module](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) to understand which template file is in use.